# Get the newest added records in the database

Tags: mysql, database, select-query

I can only describe the question by example..
If I have this data

```
    use-id         user-name          add-date
---------------------------------------------------
    2              sami               17/1/2011
    2              sami               18/1/2011
    3              alaa               18/1/2011
    4              jamal              19/1/2011
```

I want to select the newest row for each user, I want this data to result :

```
    use-id         user-name          add-date
---------------------------------------------------
    2              sami               18/1/2011
    3              alaa               18/1/2011
    4              jamal              19/1/2011
```

for each unique user-id I want to get the newsest added record. how ?

Comment: Thanks for this question, I need the answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to get the date of the newest record for each user:

```
select `use-id`, max(`add-date`) as `latest` 
from <table_name> 
group by `use-id`
```

We'll call that query `newest_records`, and use it to select only those rows that have the latest date:

```
select a.*
from <table_name>
inner join newest_records b
on a.`use-id` = b.`use-id` and a.`add-date` = b.`latest`
```

---

Edit:

Putting it all together (copy/paste), we have:

```
select a.*
from <table_name>
inner join (  
  select `use-id`, max(`add-date`) as `latest` 
  from <table_name> 
  group by `use-id`) b
on a.`use-id` = b.`use-id` and a.`add-date` = b.`latest`
```

Comment: Why do need the second query? doesn't the first do what is required ?

Comment: @Bader -- no, the first query only gets the `use-id` and `date` -- **not the entire rows**.  The second query uses the first to get the rest of the columns in the rows of interest.  Of course you could combine them into one query, I just thought splitting them up made it look clearer.

Comment: thanks, select `use-id`,`use-name`, max(`add-date`) as `latest` 
from <table_name> 
group by `use-id`   .. is correct ?

Comment: @Bader -- **No!!!**  You should **never** select non-group-by columns without aggregate functions (unless you want strange things to happen)!  That's why the query is slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it `User-Id` determines `User-Name` (`User-Id --> User-Name`). That means there won't be two equal `User-Id`s with different `User-Name`s. And your data clearly shows this with `User-Id` number 2, which both have the same `User-Name` (`sami`).

So it would be valid to do a simpler and more efficient query:

```
select user-id, user-name, max(add-date) from table1
group by user-id, user-name
```

Note: MySql also allows you to remove the `user-name` from the group by

Now, clearly your table is lacking [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Your table should look like this:

`YourTable(User-Id, Add-Date)`

And you should also have another table `Users` that should look like this:

`Users(User-Id, User-Name)`

And to get the result you're expecting in this new schema you should joing both tables.